# Java FX in Ubuntu with JDK7 (FX path?)

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu, javafx, java-7

In order to use Java FX in Netbeans I installed java jdk 7 by [ppa](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/09/how-to-install-oracle-java-7-jdk-in.html).
According to a Netbeans [instruction](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javafx-setup.html) I tried to enable JavaFX in the Java Platforms in Netbeans. The problem is that I have to enter the paths to FX:

[image: Enabling JavaFX in Netbeans]

*Note: This image is only an example from the instruction, my platform is "JDK 1.7".*

Where is JavaFX located when installed with jdk7 by ppa?
(I checked the java version and it is `1.7.0_03`so FX should be included)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think JavaFX is co-bundled in the version of Java which you installed.

I believe you (currently) need to:

1. Get the [JavaFX Linux developer preview from Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html) separately to the Linux distribution of the JDK.
2. Follow the installation instructions in the [official JavaFX preview for Linux release notes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2.0/release_notes_linux/jfxpub-release_notes_linux.htm).
3. Supplement that with information from [weiqi gao's blog](http://www.weiqigao.com/blog/2012/02/03/running_32_bit_javafx_2_1_beta_sdk_on_64_bit_ubuntu_11_10.html) if you need help on getting the JavaFX supported media codecs working under Linux.
4. Follow the instructions from NetBeans to setup a [JavaFX platform under NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/javafx-setup.html).

Comment: Somehow I suspected it... But why does Oracle state `Starting with Java SE 7 Update 2, the JDK includes the JavaFX SDK.` on this [page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html)?

Comment: That statement is only currently true for Windows, perhaps the text was written when only a Windows version of JavaFX 2 existed, in which case it was obvious that it could only apply to Windows.  If you like, you can ask Oracle to update the page to clarify it (doc feedback email alias is jfx-docs-feedback_ww@oracle.com)

Answer (score 1):

Its now co-bundled with JDK 7 for Windows, Mac and Linux .. see: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/index.html

basically you would need to enable JavaFX .. just add the same JDK manually and check if it has JAVAFX SDK .. if not, then install JDK7 ( mine is JDK1.7.0_22 ) , follow this how to install JDK on ubuntu 12.10 : http://www.vikramtakkar.com/2013/02/how-to-install-oracle-jdk-7-to-ubuntu.html

and then just select that JDK via Java platforms and enable JavaFX .. and its gonna work

my ubuntu is 12.10 64-bit

good luck